# Apps purchases pop-up options

Tags: iphone, ios-appstore, password, settings, dialog

Whenever I am trying to dowanload free apps from the store it asks me about additional purchases. I am unable to understand this . Please help

[image]

Comment: Please use a pic editor to resize your screenshot or an appropriate html command to adjust the size of the pic!

Answer (score 2):

To buy something on the App Store you have to type your password.

If you choose "always require", every time you buy something, App Store will ask your password.

If you choose "Require after 15 minutes", for the first purchase you will have to type your password, then you would be able to buy everything on the App Store for 15 minutes without typing your password again. 
After 15 minutes, App Store will ask your password again.